# Pattern to force user to set preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, usability

My application requires connection to a server, hence it will not work without set preferences. The preferences are set using `SharedPreferences`. What I am looking for is a pattern to direct the user to the settings activity. What is common?

Currently I am checking on `onCreate` and `onResume` whether all preferences are set, otherwise I start the settings activity. The problem is:

1. the activity is started twice (through `onCreate` and `onResume`)
2. the user might not know that he/she can go back to the main activity with the back hardware key

Any suggestions to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a LauncherActivity class where you can make the decision which Activity should start - PreferenceActivity, or MainActivity: check [this](http://www.blackmoonit.com/2010/02/android-always-create-launcher-activity/) advice also

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences settings;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        if (settings.getBoolean(PREFS_REG, false)) {
            startActivity( new Intent(this, MAinActivity.class) );
            finish();
        } else {
             Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
         startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, SETTINGS);
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == SETTINGS ) {
             startActivity( new Intent(this, MAinActivity.class) );
             Editor editor = settings.edit();
             editor.putBoolean(PREFS_REG, true);
             editor.commit();
             finish();
        }

    }
}
```

And if user "registered" then set the PREFS_REG to *true* in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: If you use this method, I don't think you want to `finish()` the `LauncherActivity` as then when the user pressed back, there will be no activity in the stack and it will return to the previous app. Also, if you remove the `finish()`, you will need to put all this into the `onResume` method otherwise you will just see a blank activity. Personally, I think calling `startActivity` from the `onResume` of the `MainActivity` is a better solution, which is what the OP is currently doing.

Comment: Is this really a good idea to insert another activity? From a decoupling point of view it seems reasonable, but I could imagine it complicates the manner, for instance when a preference was unset again.

Comment: @erandir In this Launcher Activity you can create a Weolcome screen, or a term of useage - then you can add some Continue button which is navigate to the Preferences Activity and if the user is registered, then Launcher activity will navigate to MainActivity automatically. I think most apps works like this

Comment: see [Always create LauncerActivity](http://www.blackmoonit.com/2010/02/android-always-create-launcher-activity/)

Answer (score 1):

1. `onResume` will always be called after `onCreate`, therefore you only need to perform the check and start the new activity in the `onResume` method.
2. You could display a `Toast` when the `SettingsActivity` loads, such as:

   ```
   Toast.makeText(context, "Press back to return.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```

You may also wish to show a `Toast` or `AlertDialog` when the `SettingsActivity` starts telling the user that they must enter these settings before they can use the app.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you show a Popup Dialog with a message like "set preferences first" with a button to open your Settings Activity. The check for SharedPreferences and opening the Dialog can be done in onResume. 
 And close the Settings Activity automatically when user finishes editing settings (and presses save-Button).